# How do I install, update and remove GNOME Shell Extensions?

Tags: software-installation, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

I am running Ubuntu GNOME and would like to know how exactly I can install, uninstall, upgrade, deactivate, and activate GNOME Shell Extensions.